# Disabling NServiceBus Marketing Pop-up in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nservicebus

Every time we open Visual Studio, the following tab is opened:

[image]

**Is there a way to disable this behavior?**

Perhaps to ask this in a more generic way, in which it would be helpful in other applications, **can you disable extensions/dependencies from screwing with your Visual Studio layout?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My colleagues and I had the same problem a few years ago. 
You can disable the pop up manually by setting a registry string value at:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\NServiceBus\{Major.Minor}]
```

Called `MachinePrepared` with a value of `true`.

Answer (score 4):

The web page should pop up only once, when you have installed NServiceBus for the very first time via Nuget. It popping up every time is an anomaly and I agree, is very annoying. That said, we are in the process of removing the Visual Studio Popup starting from Versions 6.1.0 and above. You can find the details of that change here: https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/pull/4280

For the current version that is annoying you, i.e. the solution that you're opening that's causing this behavior, can you have a look at the init.ps1 from the nuget package and check to see the registry keys are present?
Feel free to reach out to us directly by opening a support incident here:
https://particular.net/support

Hope this helps. Cheers.